# Route Model Binding Not Firing

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have some route/model bindings setup. Around ten of them for various ids. Nothing special going on:

```
$router->get('/notifications/{active_notification_id}/open', 'NotificationsController@open');

$router->bind('active_notification_id', function ($id)
{
    echo 'here'; echo $id; exit;

    // code
});
```

The binding is not firing at all. Works fine in eight others but for two of them it just doesn't fire. It goes straight to the controller with an empty model which than crashes my code.

The crazier thing is they ALL work on my local box just fine (Windows) but only having this issue on server (Ubuntu). My php versions are off by just one minor version. But 8 of the bindings work, it's just those two simply won't fire.

Anyone have an idea?

- Note my Laravel and package versions are the same on both ends.

UPDATE: So actually it seems none of my routes will echo out on production. I "assumed" the others were working because they worked correctly. I also tried editing the `src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php bind()` function to echo something but can't see it echo on production (does on local).

There must be some kind of class/file caching on my production box. Not sure if this is Laravel issue or something with my DigitialOcean box.

Comment: Ubuntu is case sensitive system, so if class is called e.g: `MyExampleClass` than file should have name `MyExampleClass.php`, what error do you get?

Comment: That's the thing I'm not getting any errors related to syntax and such. When I print out the model in the controller it's just an empty model. So everything is "working", but the route/model binding is not firing.

Comment: Is it possible there is some kind of caching for these bindings that I need to reset?

Comment: You could try `php artisan route:clear` to clear the route cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to Laravels pre-compiling.

The framework **pre-compiles** certain classes that are used on basically every request. This serves the purpose of performance optimization. Files to compile can be specified in `config/compile.php` under `files`. The [default one](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/compile.php) looks like this:

```
'files' => [
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php'),
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/BusServiceProvider.php'),
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/ConfigServiceProvider.php'),
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php'),
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php'),
],
```

When running `php artisan optimize` when debugging is not enabled (or with the `--force` option) Those listed files and other framework classes will be written to `storage/framework/compiled.php`. (in Laravel 5.0.16 the path has been changed to `vendor/compiled.php`)

Try running `php artisan clear-compiled` or `php artisan optimize` and your "new" `RouteServiceProvider` should be used.

---

#### Background info

`php artisan optimize` is called every time you run `composer update` `composer install` (and `composer create-project`) because it is registered as post script:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Ya, I was thinking about that too, but don't remember running it and there is no compiled.php file there (Although I just ran a composer update (which fixed it), not sure if that deletes it).

Comment: Laravel registers two `post-update-cmd`s. `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize`. I suppose it didn't regenerate the compiled file because you turned debugging on. Am I right?`

Comment: Just confirmed that a `composer update` does in fact remove this file, so that must have been it. Don't remember running that command, but who knows.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you ran `composer update` before. How would you get your dependencies otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting bind section before defining route.

```
$router->bind('active_notification_id', function ($id)
{
    echo 'here'; echo $id; exit;

    // code
});

$router->get('/notifications/{active_notification_id}/open', 'NotificationsController@open');
```

Comment: The route and binding are in separate files (standard to Laravel 5).