# Why am I getting and "Undefined variable: var" error in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've been trying to pass some data to be avaliable in my views but after following several guides I always get a `Undefined variable: var` error.

I've added to `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` in 2 different attemps:

Using share():

```
public function boot()
{
        // Make this custom global data avaliable to all views
        $var = "Foobar";
        view()->share('var', $var);
}
```

Using composer():

```
public function boot()
    {
            view()->composer('partials.navbar', function($view){
                $view->with('var', 'Foobar');
            });
    }
```

resources/views/partials/navbar.blade.php:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="somewhere">{{$var}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm completely new to Laravel so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that you are a victim of laravel pre-compiling the service providers... Run `php artisan clear-compiled` and try again

Comment: @lukasgeiter `php artisan clear-compiled`:`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedCompilePath()`

Comment: removing `/vendor/compiled.php` and running it again fixed it. Everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Just wanted to suggest that... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel pre-compiles certain files to improve performance. The `AppServiceProvider` is one of them...

To clear the pre-compiled classes, run `php artisan clear-compiled` and to pre-compile them again run `php artisan optimize`.

To change the classes that are pre-compiled and for more information on the topic in general, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28925512/1903366)